# Remove CSS styling from mega menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a Wordpress site at the site: https://mimsi.dk/. The menu first looked like this and I need to make it look like this again:

[image: Before install of mega menu]

Because we have added a lot of sub menus I had to add a Mega Menu (WP Mega Menu PRO). The problem is now that I need to make the Mega Menu look like the old menu, shown above.

If I remove the following line I get the menu on the top:

```
body.admin-bar .banner[data-transparent-header="true"] {
    top: 32px;
}
```

But how can I remove the background and hover effect so I only get the text, like the old menu looked like? I cannot find the classes I have to add or remove in the inspect window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the image that you have shared since imgur is blocked in my country. However, you can change the background styling of your menu in the following code block. Find it in your CSS file and change as you wish it to be.

```
.wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmega-black-white.wpmm-orientation-horizontal,
.wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmega-black-white.wpmm-orientation-vertical{
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(50%,#3d3d3d),color-stop(50%,#3d3d3d),color-stop(50%,#212121));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3d3d3d,#212121);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#3d3d3d,#212121);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#3d3d3d,#212121);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#3d3d3d,#212121);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```